# What do these non-browser icons mean in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, installation

I was looking for a meaning of these icons. I tried to use Google, but most results were for the project browser.They appear when you're looking at eclipse installation details.
[Icon has a light red square on top right and red cross on it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLM8a.png)

Comment: I think it just means this is a feature patch

Comment: Thank you. I wish they added meanings of other icons in the documentation too.

Comment: Well, it's an open source project so there is no _they_. You might contribute to the documentation contained in [this Git repository](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.common.git/).